# sending email using zend/mail

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2

I want to send an email using zend/mail in zend framework 2. 
I already have some code but i don't know where to put it, and also not how to trigger this.

```
$mail = new Mail\Message();
        $mail->setBody('This is the text of the email.');
        $mail->setFrom('email@hotmail.be', 'email');
        $mail->addTo('email@hotmail.be', 'email');
        $mail->setSubject('Dit is een email verzonden van de computer');

$transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail('-freturn_to_email@hotmail.be');
$transport->send($mail);
```

I still new at Zend framework 2.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Can you explain what your problem is? What have you tried? Do you use Zend\Mvc? Do you only use a small php script? What is your goal?

Comment: The problem is that it don't send an email. Yess, i'm using Zend\Mvc. I'm just trying to send a simple email for now. Later on it has to send an email on a specific hour of the day. But for now i was trying to send a "simple" email. I tried almost everything that I found on the framework.zend.com/manual website. I don't know what to do to make it work. Also Thank you for answering this question.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a problem with sendmail? Can you send emails okay using the PHP `mail()` command?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to take a look at [Soflomo\Mail](http://github.com/Soflomo/Mail). Note, I am the author of Soflomo mail, but it helps you a lot with sending mails. It eases the config and dependency hassle.

Put `"soflomo/mail": "~0.3"` in your `composer.json` file and run the following command:

```
php composer.phar update soflomo/mail
```

Next, enable the module `Soflomo\Mail` in your `application.config.php`. When you use Zend\Mvc, you will have a controller/action which should trigger the email. For the most simplified use case, you can do this:

```php
public function doAction()
{
    // some of your logic

    $service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Soflomo\Mail\Service\MailService');
    $service->send(array(
        'to'        => 'email@hotmail.be',
        'to_name'   => 'email',

        'from'      => 'email@hotmail.be',
        'from_name' => 'email',

        'subject'   => 'Dit is een email verzonden van de computer',
        'template'  => 'mail/message/default'
   ));
}
```

Now Soflomo\Mail sends a message by rendering a template and use that as message text. Here I defined a message `mail/message/default` so create that file (e.g. `module/Application/view/mail/message/default.phtml`) with this content:

```
This is the text of the email.
```

The last thing to do is to configure how Soflomo/Mail sends the message. Your question uses Sendmail, so I am using this as well in this example. Create a configuration file in config/autoload , e.g. `config/autoload/soflomo_mail.global.php` which contains the following content:

```
return array(
    'soflomo_mail' => array(
        'transport' => array(
            'type' => 'sendmail',
        ),
    ),
);
```

If you want to switch to e.g. GMail as transport layer, replace above config with:

```
return array(
    'soflomo_mail' => array(
        'transport' => array(
            'type'    => 'smtp',
            'options' => array(
                'name' => 'gmail.com',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'port' => 587,
                'connection_class'  => 'login',
                'connection_config' => array(
                    'ssl'      => 'tls',
                    'username' => '%USERNAME%',
                    'password' => '%PASSWORD%',
                ),
            ),
            'variables' => array(
                'username' => '',
                'password' => '',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

And create a new file `config/autoload/soflomo_mail.local.php`:

```
return array(
    'soflomo_mail' => array(
        'transport' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'username' => 'my-address@gmail.com',
                'password' => '1234secure7890',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

I guess Hotmail would be similar to GMail.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this within the zend directory,

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
$mail->setFrom('somebody@example.com', 'Some Sender');
$mail->addTo('somebody_else@example.com', 'Some Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->send();
```

Comment: Question is about ZF2, not ZF1